# Is there a way I can print the output of an input I converted on a singular line?

Tags: python, encoding

I was making this emoji encoder and basically I need to make it so that it prints the output of the
inputted text on one line instead of each character on separate lines. Right Now it just inputs the encoded text(the emojis) on separate lines, is there any way I can make it output on just one line. Any suggestions?

Edit: I solved the problem thanks everyone :)

```
import emoji

# Ascii Art

print('\n'
      ' ________                                 __        ________                                      __                     \n'
      '/        |                               /  |      /        |                                    /  |                    \n'
      '$$$$$$$$/  _____  ____    ______      __ $$/       $$$$$$$$/  _______    _______   ______    ____$$ |  ______    ______  \n'
      '$$ |__    /     \/    \  /      \    /  |/  |      $$ |__    /       \  /       | /      \  /    $$ | /      \  /      \ \n'
      '$$    |   $$$$$$ $$$$  |/$$$$$$  |   $$/ $$ |      $$    |   $$$$$$$  |/$$$$$$$/ /$$$$$$  |/$$$$$$$ |/$$$$$$  |/$$$$$$  |\n'
      '$$$$$/    $$ | $$ | $$ |$$ |  $$ |   /  |$$ |      $$$$$/    $$ |  $$ |$$ |      $$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$    $$ |$$ |  $$/ \n'
      '$$ |_____ $$ | $$ | $$ |$$ \__$$ |   $$ |$$ |      $$ |_____ $$ |  $$ |$$ \_____ $$ \__$$ |$$ \__$$ |$$$$$$$$/ $$ |      \n'
      '$$       |$$ | $$ | $$ |$$    $$/    $$ |$$ |      $$       |$$ |  $$ |$$       |$$    $$/ $$    $$ |$$       |$$ |      \n'
      '$$$$$$$$/ $$/  $$/  $$/  $$$$$$/__   $$ |$$/       $$$$$$$$/ $$/   $$/  $$$$$$$/  $$$$$$/   $$$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/ $$/       \n'
      '                               /  \__$$ |                                                                                \n'
      '                               $$    $$/                                                                                 \n'
      '                                $$$$$$/          \n'
      '                                                                                                            \n'
      '\n')

# Intro Loading Screen

print("Enter text to be encoded Here:")
text = input()

# Encoder for lower case

if "a" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':grinning_face:'))

if "b" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes:'))

if "c" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':beaming_face_with_smiling_eyes:'))

if "d" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':grinning_squinting_face:'))

if "e" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':grinning_face_with_sweat:'))

if "f" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':rolling_on_the_floor_laughing:'))

if "g" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':face_with_tears_of_joy:'))

if "h" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':slightly_smiling_face:'))

if "i" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':upside-down_face:'))

if "j" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':winking_face:'))

if "k" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':smiling_face_with_smiling_eyes:'))

if "l" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':smiling_face_with_halo:'))

if "m" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':smiling_face_with_hearts:'))

if "n" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':smiling_face_with_heart-eyes:'))

if "o" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':star-struck:'))

if "p" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':face_blowing_a_kiss:'))

if "q" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':kissing_face:'))

if "r" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':grinning_face:'))

if "s" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':smiling_face:'))

if "t" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':kissing_face_with_closed_eyes:'))

if "u" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':kissing_face_with_smiling_eyes:'))

if "v" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':face_savoring_food:'))

if "w" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':face_with_tongue:'))

if "x" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':winking_face_with_tongue:'))

if "y" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':squinting_face_with_tongue:'))

if "z" in text:
    print(emoji.emojize(':money-mouth_face:'))
```

Comment: you're missing input, output, and expected output. (and please remove anything that isn't pertinent to your question)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I understand.

Comment: In a question about something that "isn't working" you need to show us, i.e. you need to show us the data you're using, the output of your program with that data, and what output you expected. In other words, make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put your letter: emoji mapping into a dict:

```
emoji_map = {
    "a": ':grinning_face:',
    "b": ':grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes:',
    # etc
}
```

and then you can easily reformat your output, add new mappings, etc without having to change a bunch of individual if statements.  For example, to put everything on one line:

```
print("Enter text to be encoded Here:")
text = input()

print(''.join(emoji_map.get(c.lower(), '') for c in text))
```

Comment: -1 If `text` has multiple `a`s, then this code will make duplicate emojis, while OP's code won't (it should loop through the dictionary instead of the text).

Answer (score 0):

The print() function always prints on a new line.  You want to create a variable to take in all of the emojis, then print only once.  If you are dealing with strings, for example, append to the strings.

```
emojis_to_output = ''
if "a" in text:
    emojis_to_output += emoji.emojize(':grinning_face:')

# ...  and so on ...
if "z" in text:
    emojis_to_output += emoji.emojize(':money-mouth_face:')

print(emojis_to_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

A thing that I haven't seen any answers say is the `print` function's `end` argument:

> print(*objects, sep=' ', **end='\n'**, file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep **and followed by end**. sep, end, file and flush, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.

So, for each of your `print` statements, you could do this:

```
print(emoji.emojize(':grinning_face:'), end="")
```

However, you are doing a lot - and I mean a *lot* - of unnecessary hard coding. Instead of having 26 `if` statements, just make a dictionary with all your values!

```py
emojis = {
    "a": ":grinning_face:",
    "b": ":grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes:",
    # ... and on and on ...
}

for key in emojis:
    if key in text:
        print(emoji.emojize(emojis[key]), end="")
print() # Add a final new line
```

Or, you could even make this a one-liner!

```py
print("".join(key in text and emoji.emojize(emojis.get(key)) for key in emojis))
```